# Is there a reason to downvote questions if they garner enough flags to be on hold?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, on-hold

Is there a particular reason why one would downvote a question before/after it becomes [on hold]? Is it purely to tell the question's author "hey, you need to put some more effort into your questions."? Often times I find myself just flagging a question rather than downvoting it, unless its a really bad question such as "Can you do my homework for me?"

Comment: One reason is the roomba.  If the Q has a rouge up vote and is closed it will not get deleted.  If you cast a down vote then it will be eligible for deletion.

Comment: Yes. it could always be reopened, but the downvotes would remain. they're two different tools with two different purposes.

Comment: Downvotes aren't there for the author (primarily).  They're there for everyone else, to know that that's a question that isn't worth their time, and for the system to know that the user asked a bad question.  If a question is bad enough for you to want to close it, it's almost certainly not actually a useful question, meaning it merits a downvote.  Exceptions to that should be quite rare.

Comment: @NathanOliver Does this also apply to questions marked as duplicates that get downvoted?

Comment: @Javia1492 No.  Duplicates are not rommba'd.

Comment: Correcting @NathanOliver, duplicates are not deleted by the closedAbandoned rules, but they may qualify by the other two.

Comment: If the question isn't salvageable, it allows users to vote to delete after closure.

Comment: Another side effect of the downvote is that if pushes the OP closer to a question ban. If you think that his behaviour is so bad that he should be banned from asking new questions, then you should consider downvoting.

Comment: If a question is bad enough that it requires a close vote, then why would it not also deserve a downvote?

Comment: @JK.:  Because a question may be a duplicate but not a bad question.  It's important to disambiguate downvotes from close votes in that context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a question isn't useful, regardless of what state it's in, it's eligible and subject to downvotes.  Depending on the content that may mean it will never recover - like "Do my homework for me"-type questions - but a vote can be undone if a question (or answer) is edited, and that edit is done outside of the ~5 minute grace period for edits.

They're not really for the author, but they are the person they hit directly; it tells the world that this question isn't useful, and the author gets that indirectly.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a particular reason why one would downvote a question before/after it becomes [on hold]?

Question closure is about topicality. Questions that are off-topic or do not contain adequate information to be answered (or they do contain adequate information but it is drowned out by massive amounts of irrelevant information) should be closed.

Question voting is about usefulness, clarity, and perceived research effort (among other things). If it does not show any research effort, is unclear or not useful then it should be downvoted regardless of the close/open status of the question.

It is possible (though uncommon) to find a question that is useful and shows research effort, but it just plain off-topic. In such cases it would not be appropriate (though acceptable, anyone can vote for any reason—or lack thereof—that they like) to downvote while it would be appropriate to close vote.

Similarly, it is possible to (and somewhat more common) to find a question that shows no research effort or is not useful, but *is* on-topic. In such cases it is appropriate to downvote, but not appropriate to close vote.

Comment: Wouldnt unclear be flagged "should be closed->unclear what you're asking" or does it have to be unclear and off-topic for that flag to apply?

Comment: I don't get the downvote here.  This answer is exactly correct.  Downvoting and close voting are orthogonal.  They do intercept each other so doing both is a common action but it also means if you do one action 
it does not mean you must do the other action

Comment: @Javia You can close vote as unclear _and_ downvote as unclear, if it is in fact unclear. You can also downvote for any number of reasons not mentioned here.